# How to implement querystring inside the sql insert query in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, query-string

I have a problem `FK UserId` where my insert query. It should be get UserId automatically. I suppose; I need a querystring for calling the UserId from anotherpage. But I can't embed it. 
My insert query:

> string query = "Insert into Conferences (conferenceName,
>   conferenceDate, conferencePlace, submissionDuedate,
>   conferenceDescription , category, status, PaperID, UserId) Values
>   (@conferanceName, @conferenceDate, @conferencePlace,
>   @submissionDuedate, @conferenceDescription, @category, @PaperID

here it should be querystring as like `Request.QueryString["UserId"].ToString())";`
How can I do this?

Comment: You would substitute the value from the query string when you populate the parameter values.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to give an answer. Try posting the entire function so we can see what you are talking about. You seem to be confused by "sql query string" and "querystring", which are two completely different concepts.

Comment: I know the differences between two. I need to call variable from another page in my sql query. Normally I'm using querystring to call the value from another page but now I need to call value inside the sql query. @Maxx

Comment: Is the User ID in the query string?  If it is, simply retrieve the value and add it to the UserID parameter.   If it's not, then you need to add it to the query string.  To put it another way, where is the User ID and what is the problem you're having trying to get it?

Comment: Your above comment does not make sense. Please post the entire function so we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

string query = "Insert into Conferences (conferenceName, conferenceDate, conferencePlace, submissionDuedate, conferenceDescription , category, status, PaperID, UserId) Values (@conferanceName, @conferenceDate, @conferencePlace, @submissionDuedate, @conferenceDescription, @category, @PaperID," & Request.QueryString["UserId"].ToString()) & ")"